# Is there any way to remove certain keywords as email, phone numbers from audio file (.wav), without converting it to text?

Tags: azure, speech-recognition

I have an audio file with information like email, phone numbers, etc. I want to remove this kind of information without loss of original voice.

I used the following approach with python:

1. First I converted the audio to text and then removed those
   information and again converted it to audio.
2. This way I lost the original voice of the person.

Is there any way that I can achieve this without loss of original voice?
This is the code I used to convert audio to text using azure API.

```
def stream_audio_file(speech_file, chunk_size=1024):
    # chunk audio file
    with open(speech_file, 'rb') as f:
        while 1:
            data = f.read(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            yield data
```

How to remove some information from audio without losing the original voice?

Answer (score 0):

Get word timestamps from the recognizer and remove the signal at required periods. Check ["AddWordLevelTimestamps"](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/cognitive-services/Speech-Service/batch-transcription.md) configuration option.